# Ubuntu randomly freezes (mouse still moves)

Tags: 16.04, gnome, freeze

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T460p with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS installed. It freezes randomly, but I can move the cursor without clicking. It happens:

- When searching in the gnome shell (some terms are more freezing-prone than others).
- When working on Libre office

In both cases a CPU usage spike happens. On Gnome shell some times the PC recovers after 5-10 seconds and continues working normally.

I have looked around to similar threads and tried the following without success:

- To update
- To change to NVDIA propietary drivers
- To change desktop environment to KDE (problem solved, but I'd like to use Gnome)
- To disable all extensions

Any ideas?

Results of `journalctl -xe` [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0AEJeIN1bWFRDE0X1BxOHdzZ00) (too long to copy here).

EDIT: add new things I tried which didn't work. Posted link to journalctl -xe

Comment: Are you using extensions? What happens if you disable them all?

Comment: Just tried disabling them all, still happens.

Comment: What does `journalctl -xe` show? If you're able to reproduce this issue consistently, the problem should be easy to identify. Separately, are any errors generated when these freezes occur?

Comment: Just posted the output in a link in the main question. No, no errors generated.